# ユーザー関数の定義をどのように記述すればよいか分からない

Tags: c

ユーザー関数の練習で、入力した数字に5を足して3倍した値を求めたいのですが、`calc` の部分に何を書けばいいのか分かりません。教えてもらえるとありがたいです。
`calc()//記述` の部分以外は変更できません。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

calc()//記述

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    y = calc(x);
    printf("Answer=%d", y);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: 関数を使わずに「数時に5を足して3倍した値」を求めることはできますか？

Comment: 関数を使わないといけないのでできません

Comment: 課題等でそのような指定がされているのかもしれませんが、私がコメントしたのは分からない部分が「関数の書き方」なのか「四則演算の書き方」なのかを確認するためです。

Comment: すいません両方わからないので、教えてもらえるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 1):

回答貰うのは簡単でしょうが、質問者さんのためになりません。基礎からしっかり勉強されることをお勧めします。

```
// まず関数の書き方だけ
int calc(int x) {
    return x; // x をそのまま返す。四則演算はご自分で考えてみましょう。
}
```

Answer (score 1):

回答例です。参考サイトが参考になると思います。

参考サイト：https://www.sejuku.net/blog/24348

```c
int calc(int x)
{
    return (x + 5) * 3;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

[C言語入門](https://webkaru.net/clang/) のようなページが、"C言語" "入門"　"初心者"といったキーワードで検索すると見つかると思います。

Googleなどの検索サイトを活用するのは、最も基礎的なネットワークリテラシーですよ。